# phonestatelistener is not called for sim slot 2

Tags: android, listener, state, phone-call, dual-sim

I have a dual SIM (slot 0 and slot 1) phone.
I have the phonestatelistener in my service. This listener receives the callback only when the
SIM in the sim slot 0 receives the call. This listener is not getting callback when a
call comes for SIM in SIM slot 1.

I have swapped the SIM and confirmed that irrespective of the SIM the phonestatelistener getting callback for the SIM in the SIM slot 0 only.

I couldn't' understand the issue.

Please let me know what could be the problem

```
Phone model samsung galaxy s duos 2 (GT-S7562) OS jelly bean 4.2.2
```

**Homeservice.java**

```
public class Homeservice extends Service{


   TelephonyManager telephonyManager;  
   PhoneStateListener listener;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


         // Get the telephony manager    
         telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

         // Create a new PhoneStateListener    
         listener = new PhoneStateListener() {      

         @Override      
         public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) { 


             switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        //finish something
                            break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        //do somethings
                        break; 
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
                        break;
                        } 
                    }
                };


                // Register the listener wit the telephony manager              
                telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);




    }




    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return START_STICKY;



    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }




}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<service
        android:name="com.kabil.homeservice"
        >
   </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

`PhoneStateListener` have another constructor `PhoneStateListener(Integer subId)` where you can pass your sim subscription id to the constructor and it will do the remaining task as it is.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of TelephoneManager is tied to a specific SIM (subscriptionId). Use [TelephonyManager.createForSubscription](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#createForSubscriptionId(int)) to obtain an instance for the SIM slot you desire.

Comment: It is available from API 24. What is for previous versions.